# Fatal error while running php artisan serve>

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new to Laravel. I don't why this isn't working.

```
user@user-MS-7529:~/blog$ php artisan key:generate --ansi
PHP Warning:  require(/home/user/blog/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/blog/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/user/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/user/blog/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/blog/artisan on line 18
```

Comment: can you please provide more information by running php -v in terminal and posting your directory structure of blog...

Comment: user@user-MS-7529:~$ php -v
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:53:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run laravel 5 app without php artisan serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504651/run-laravel-5-app-without-php-artisan-serve)

Comment: no it doesn't thanks anyway error has been fixed thanks for you time bro!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for  your precious time the error has now been fixed
This caused error because during the time making laravel project it has caused some error in my case
php-mbstring and php-xml was not availabe or installed on my system somehow.
you can simply fixed it by

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install php-mbstring**

or if got the older version

**sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring**

**sudo apt install php-xml**

And boom your error got fixed!!!Hope this could be useful in future

Answer (score 0):

Install Composer ..

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Make sure you have run:

```
composer install
```

Now it seems packages are not installed. If they are, try running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then run

```
composer global update
```

Try to to give permission for that vendor folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vendor
```

update your composer also

```
composer update
```

Comment: sorry but didn't worked user@user-MS-7529:~/blog$ composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in /home/user/blog/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/blog/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/blog/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Comment: After that you try composer global update

Comment: please try this also ...composer global update

Comment: after running user@user-MS-7529:~/blog$ composer global update
Changed current directory to /home/user/.config/composer
Composer is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have the PHP curl extension enabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
10 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: no it didn't solve the error still getting same error

Comment: which operating system are you using .,..You have to install php-curl ...Which version of php are you running ...

Comment: i am using elmentory os and php-curl is already installed php version is 8.0.3

Comment: if its a debian flavour simply run sudo apt-get install php-curl

Comment: ok i have installed it whats the next step?

Comment: what error do you get now when you run composer global update

Comment: user@user-MS-7529:/etc/php/8.0/apache2/conf.d$ ls
10-opcache.ini   20-exif.ini      20-gettext.ini  20-readline.ini  20-sysvsem.ini
10-pdo.ini       20-ffi.ini       20-iconv.ini    20-shmop.ini     20-sysvshm.ini
20-calendar.ini  20-fileinfo.ini  20-phar.ini     20-sockets.ini   20-tokenizer.ini
20-ctype.ini     20-ftp.ini       20-posix.ini    20-sysvmsg.ini

Comment: i am unable to enable curl extension

Comment: Changed current directory to /home/user/.config/composer
Composer is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have the PHP curl extension enabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
10 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
 this was the output

Comment: just uninstall phpcurl and reinstall it by running sudo apt-get install php8.0-curl

Comment: ok i have uninstalled it and installed new one now ?

Comment: please run composer global update and provide output

Comment: user@user-MS-7529:~/blog$ composer global update
Changed current directory to /home/user/.config/composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
10 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: please tell the output of php artisan key:generate --ansi

Comment: Error is same as before i thought it might be the problem with my os so i reinstallled it same problem I think i am doing something wrong

Comment: Bro error has been fixed thanks for your time though. Really appreciated and now i feel so relief now for minute I thought i will quite the programming haha

Comment: I am so glad that your error got resolved... please comment how the error has been resolved...

Comment: Thanks again bro!! Error because during the time making laravel project it has caused some error in my case php-mbstring and php-xml was not availabe or installed on my system somehow. you can simply fixed it by

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

or if got the older version

sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring

sudo apt install php-xml

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you have installed composer properly. use **composer** in terminal or CMD in your OS. If composer is properly installed you will see a  composer ascii art in terminal or in cmd.
2. Assuming composer is installed properly then check with the version of the laravel you have installed. You can do this by opening the composer.json file and check for "laravel/framework". Alternatively you can run this command in your project directory in a terminal **php artisan --version**.
3. Now check your PHP version. You can use  to check what version of PHP you are running on. If you are using latest laravel framework then you need at least PHP 7.3.0.

Also if you have pulled the codebase from git then you need to run **composer update** in your project directory to get all the packages installed in vendor folder.

Comment: user@user-MS-7529:~/blog$ php artisan --version
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in /home/user/blog/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/blog/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/blog/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Comment: how did you install the laravel? did you use composer create? and what os your on? also check you php version.

Comment: yes i have used composer composer global require laravel/installer

laravel new example-app
 and i am  on linux (elementory os)

Comment: and what is your php version?

Comment: php version ->>8.0.3

Comment: do a php info and check if that module is enabled. may be you have more than one version of php installed. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: no i only have one php version but the error has been solve thank for your precious time bro